# How to Setting CSS Code styles in WebStorm?

Tags: css, webstorm, emmet

I wanna Setting below single-line format CSS Code Style in WebStorm.
(not a space included after the opening brace and before the closing brace.)

```
h1 {width:50px;height:50px;}
```

But It does not exist in Webstrom setting menu (WebStorm - Setting - Code Style - CSS )

and show below style.

```
h1 { width:50px; height:50px; }
```

How can I solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206896949-How-to-Setting-CSS-Code-styles-in-WebStorm-?flash_digest=5d1923a3cd715f7ff5207f351c9dcf6e708fa70f

This is a JetBrains Forum answer.

> there is no such option, please vote for
>   https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-236